# Knowing how many installs were made via facebook mobile app ad

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

Last week I uploaded a new app.
I started a Facebook mobile campaign, and did as was told in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/measurement/  in order to measure app installs (I added the Facebook sdk v3.5 into my apk and called the relevant api calls).

In my Facebook apps -> Insights -> Mobile App Installs page, it says:

> This dashboard shows organic and paid app installs reported by either the Facebook SDK for iOS, Facebook SDK for Android, or a Mobile Measurement Partner*. Developers should use this dashboard for debugging to ensure that app installs are being recorded. This dashboard can also be used as an indicator of app install volume** and as a baseline for understanding how ads are increasing installs of your app. For detailed data on paid installs, see the analytics in the Ads tool.

What I want to see is my ads **impressions, clicks, installs**.

What I do not understand is, are the numbers in the "Mobile App Installs" page refer to overall app installs, or only installs made via facebook ads?

Also, regarding the last sentence ("...see the analytics in the Ads tool") , I don't see any info about installs in the Ads tool (only impressions and clicks, no installs).

Does anyone know where to find the data I'm looking for?

**Edit:**

in Facebook's https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage page, only have the following data:
[image]

And there is no info regarding actual installs.
Where can the installs data be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...

My campaign was created with a google play url, and not with the facebook app I created in https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

The ad format is the same (sponsored ad in android devices), but the info I get in the dashboard is different (in https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage).

When I created an ad using a Google Play url, the is the info I have:
[image]

And when I created an ad for the facebook app I create, this is what I have:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Facebook Insights, you will see all mobile app installs reported by your app.

To see impressions, clicks and installs, you will need to view the ad report in admanager which can be accessed via:
http://facebook.com/ads/manage

Comment: I don't see any install related info in facebook's ad manage page. please see my edited question